# the value of joint if the body was out of range

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, skeleton-code

i am trying to make the Kinect able to adjust its angle automatically to be able to detect all  skeleton joints, i used loop that go through all the joint and check their value, however i don't know what is the value that stored in -for example:"skeleton.Joints[JointID.HandRight]" - if no joint was detected. Could some one help me with that using official Kinect SDK?

Comment: i don't remember tbh what is the value of join that isn't detected. Make a breakpoint in the loop on the line where you take value of it a check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `JointTrackingState` enum on each of the joints will allow you to determine if a particular `Joint` is being tracked or not.

For example: `skeleton.Joints[JointID.HandRight].TrackingState` will tell you if the joint is:

- *Tracked*: The joint is actively being tracked by the SDK and is returning data that can be trusted.
- *Inferred*: The SDK is not confident on where the joint is, but can make an educated guess.
- *NotTracked*: The joint is not being tracked and no data is available.

You can cycle through each of the joints and check their status.  Based on if it is `Tracked`, `Inferred` or `NotTracked` you can take appropriate action.

The "Skeleton Basics" example in the Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit demonstrates how to adjust a drawn skeleton based on these values.